# In the Model View Presenter pattern, can a presenter take and use two different view interfaces at the same time?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvp

I'm curious about the situation where you have a user control that you want to reuse throughout an application, but you also have a page or other control that also needs a presenter.

So say I have an upload view and control

```
public partial class UploadControlView : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IUploadView
```

but I also have a page view

```
public partial class ExcelProcessorView : System.Web.UI.Page, IExcelProcessorView
```

The upload control would be on the ExcelProcessor page, so that the user can upload a file which is handed off to some excel processing business logic.

So I have a presenter,

```
public class ExcelUploadAndProcessPresenter : IUploadPresenter
```

In the ExcelProcessorView I would wire up the presenter as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        ExcelUploadAndProcessorPresenter presenter = 
            new ExcelUploadAndProcessorPresenter(this, uploadControl);
        this.AttachPresenter(presenter);
        uploadControl.AttachPresenter(presenter);
        //init etc...
    }
```

Is this a correct use of the MVP pattern?

I'm trying to figure out what is the best practice for handling a many views to one presenter relationship.  Can MVP have a many to one relationship in this fashion.  As an alternate question I would also like to know if the MVP pattern can/should handle a situation where you have many presenters and many views (or should you only have one presenter) ?

If you see any problems with my interpretation of MVP in general, by all means go ahead and point that out.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain further how your view and control use the same logic? I can't imagine a scenario where I would have this issue. If the logic is separate, I would think you would use two presenters.

However, there's no reason one presenter cannot handle multiple views/controls, though I would only reuse a presenter for multiple views that display the same model (e.g. CRUD screens). If one view hosts another from the same presenter, I can't think of a reason why you *shouldn't* reuse your presenter (e.g. Create screen at the bottom of a List screen).

Comment: I don't follow. Would you mind posting an edit with some sample code?